# Как сравнить переменные в массиве?

Tags: pascal

В общем дано число N (2 ≤ N ≤ 2*10^5) - это кол-во ящиков. На каждом ящике - счетчик, показывающий кол-во моркови. Суть программы - должна выводить наименьшее кол-во моркови.

---

Алгоритм:

1. Ввести число N
2. Сравнить все переменные и найти наименьший.

Вопрос:

- Вводить кучу переменных это не вариант. Значит N - это массив. Правильно ли он написан? Подскажите как все осуществить?

> N: array [2..2*10^5]

- Как все переменные сравнить? Если две или три - я еще могу понять но как  200 000 тыс.?

Comment: На второй вопрос ответил в комментах, на первый отвечу словами, т.к. уже давно не писал - забыл встроенные функции.

1. Сначала читаете в гугле (или любом другом поисковике) про массивы в паскале. Желательно с примерами.
2. Затем читаете там же про работу со случайными числами. В пункте 1) можете случайно с этим столкнуться, поэтому этот пункт можно будет считать пройденным.
3. Заполняете массив случайными числами.

Все. Ну или...

4. Читаете там же (в гугле) про работу с файлами
5. Заполняете массив данными из файла

Но это так - задание на пятерку, вдруг потом пригодится)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. В таком случае необходимо использовать динамические(безразмерные) - смотрите предыдущий свой вопрос.
2. Нахождение минимального элемента Вам описал [[@BOPOH](/users/5079/bopoh)](/users/5079/bopoh) [ниже](#comments-container-156163).

Comment: Если надо найти только наименьшее (наибольшее), то зачем сортировать?

    indexMin = 1;
    indexMax = 1;
    for i := 1 to n do
    begin
        if (a[indexMin] > a[i]) then
            indexMin := i;
        if (a[indexMax] < a[i]) then
            indexMax := i;
    end;
    //a[indexMin] - наименьшее
    //a[indexMax] - Наибольшее

UPD: вместо `indexMin` можно было бы использовать и `min` - т.е. хранить сами значения, тогда вместо `a[indexMin]` надо было бы писать `min`, а вместо `indexMin := i`; писать `min := a[i]`.

Но тогда вы не смогли бы получить индекс минимального элемента

Comment: @ВОРОН, я не отрицаю, соглашаюсь с Вами. Какой вопрос `Как все переменные сравнить? ` такой ответ.

Comment: @stck, ну так видно же - человек только учится, зачем его пугать и вводить в заблуждение такими "страшными и непонятными" вычислениями.

Comment: @BOPOH, Вы наверное правы. Моя ошибка